# Get content from checked checkbox

Tags: winforms, powershell, checkbox

My problem is the following: 
I create a checkbox with the code displayed and a button. If I click the button, the checked items should be put into the `$selectedCusts` array. But whatever I've tried - nothing worked.

```
$cbheight = 0
foreach ($c in $customer) {
    $cbheight          += 20
    $checkBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox 
    $checkBox.Font     = "Microsoft Sans Serif,14"
    $checkBox.Name     = "$c"
    $checkBox.Text     = "$c"
    $checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (20, $cbheight)
    $checkbox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (345, 23)
    $checkBox.SendToBack()
    $objForm.Controls.Add($checkBox)
}

#...
$AllCustButton.Add_Click({ 
    $selectedCusts = ???
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the individual checkboxes in an array when you create them:

```
$checkBoxes = @()
foreach ($c in $customer) {
    $cbheight          += 20
    $checkBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox 
    $checkBox.Font     = "Microsoft Sans Serif,14"
    $checkBox.Name     = "$c"
    $checkBox.Text     = "$c"
    $checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (20, $cbheight)
    $checkbox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (345, 23)
    $checkBox.SendToBack()
    $objForm.Controls.Add($checkBox)
    $checkboxes += $checkbox
}
```

And then inside the `Click` event handler, filter on the value of the `Checked` property:

```
$selectedCustomers = $checkboxes |Where-Object {$_.Checked} |Select -Expand Name
```

Comment: Thats a good Idea and worked for me. But now I have the problem that $outputLabel.Text is still empty (see the other answer). Even if I change the variable to global ($global:selectedCusts) it doesn't work. Can you help me with this problem as well?

Comment: add `outputLabel.Text = "Selected Customer:" + $selectedCusts` to the Click handler as well (the Text value won't update automatically)